# Want a way to hide website content while users change their phone / tabet from portrait to landscape

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

We have a website we are developing and the transition from Portrait to Landscape and Landscape to Portrait causes the content to look large for a second. We want a way to hide website content while users change their phone / tabet from portrait to landscape.

We have set a listener to reload the page after the user rotates their screen and that works but it's the flash of unstyled content we wish to hide. Has anyone got any ideas how we can perhaps fade to black and in again during transition?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one way to avoid any screen flashes from screen orientation changes are CSS media queries:

```
body {
  background: yellow;
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    background: white;
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    background: black;
  }
}
```

You could set the orientation to to portrait or landscape, and the style will correspond correctly (there shouldn't be a lapse in style during the transition from portrait to landscape and vis-versa).

Comment: Thank you for answering, much appreciated.

Wouldn't that just change the colour based on the current orientation of the device though?

What I need really is for the site to hide the content during the change of orientation and then show it after the transition is completed.

Comment: Yes in this example, only background color would change, yet if you assign CSS classes or id's to the content that you would like to hide, this should work. Please provide the html code of the elements you would like to hide and I could show you how to implement.

Comment: Well, what we want really is to have the html background-color be black and then during the transition the body (and everything in it) would be hidden, perhaps fade to black and then reappear (fade in) after the transition has taken place.